# Run Python gRPC server without thread executor

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, process, grpc

I've run successfully example gRPC server from github with thread executor with max workers=10. Also, I could run the same server with so_reuseport options multiple times. Each server process will spawn 10 threads to process incoming requests.

The problem is to run server without thread executor, so one server should process request in main thread. It's incompatible to run server with thread executor with max workers=1

I didn't find any documentation on that. Could some one point me to an example?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What do you mean by _incompatible_?

Comment: I'd like to process request in main thread.